# App Tracking Transparency on Flutter was rejected by Apple

Tags: ios, flutter

I need help us

I have an problem with publish my flutter app on Apple Developer. My binary was rejected any times and i does't  any more ideas about this.

The support team of apple developer says this problem:

> Guideline 5.1.2 - Legal - Privacy - Data Use and Sharing

> We noticed your app accesses web content you own where you collect cookies. Cookies may be used to track users, but you do not use App Tracking Transparency to request the user's permission before collecting data used to track.

> Starting with iOS 14.5, apps on the App Store need to receive the user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework before collecting data used to track them.

But, i implemented according of docs. For showing permission request dialog i have used this library:

```
https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency
```

I'm confused because it already implemented everything that was requested.

1. App Tracking Transparency implemented
2. Permission is displayed to the user, who selects YES or NO.
3. App Tracking Information is updated here in the App Store Connect section, including Third Party Cookies.

My app accesses external links in a WebView and for that reason they are questioning the use of "App Tracking". But I implemented everything as requested by them.

My biggest question is if I'm forgetting something that may have gone unnoticed.

Anyone who can help me, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The same thing exactly happened with me twice and in both time the issue was resolved by simply sending them a video recording of the app showing the Yes/No App Tracking Transparency dialog. They just want to know when it appears to user if you implemented everything correctly. So try sending them a video recording in the resolution center as a response to that message.

Comment: Hi Roaa, it's working for me. You made my day! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're very welcome :D

Answer (score 3):

App Store Review team is always questioning the "App Tracking Transparency dialog". Even if this dialog is the first thing that appears after the app launch. (I think they just haven't launched the app).
There's no need to make a video, just add the text "The App Tracking Transparency dialog is appearing after app launch" and they will approve the app.

Comment: Tried that. They now want to see the dialog appear regardless of a video or text advising. 

I shared code showing where it is implemented and still got rejected. Seems as though it's an iOS 15+ issue.

I have tried a few thing to get the dialog to appear with no luck. Other permission dialogs may be getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official answer from Apple.
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/
[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34625385)